# Is the reCAPTCHA v3 admin console free and accessible without having a GSuite account? If so, where?

Tags: console, admin, recaptcha

I don't know where to find the Google traffic results (output) for reCAPTCHA v3 because I don't know where to find the "admin console" where the results would be output (where I could adjust parameters, etc.).

I used my regular email address (not associated with a GSuite account) when I entered the domain name for the site I'm working on and generated the site key and the secret key for the reCAPTCHA code.

I have a second email address (associated with a GSuite account I have and tied to a different email address and a completely different site from the one I'm installing the reCAPTCHA in).

The only Google-related "admin console" I've been able to find so far is the one that goes with the GSuite account (not the one I want associated with the site I'm working on).

Is there somewhere else I can find the right admin console for the reCAPTCHA info? (It seems counterintuitive that Google would claim reCAPTCHA is free and then make a user pay for GSuite to have access to the stats.)

Answer (score 0):

Use of reCAPTCHA is not tied to G Suite.

You can access the reCAPTCHA admin console here:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/site/

This is also linked from the top-right side of the homepage:
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

The specific reCAPTCHA keys will only be visible to accounts that are owners of the site. To add an owner:

1. sign in to the Google account that has access to the reCAPTCHA key you want to share
2. go to the settings for the site, accessible via the cog icon on the right side of the admin console
3. there will be a section heading "Owners"
4. add the email address of the Google account you want to allow access
5. click "Save" at the bottom of the page
6. Sign in to the Google account you added as an owner and you should now see the site in the admin console